# Laravel module system and its functioning

Tags: php, laravel, module

I am developing a similar project and using the "https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules" package for the module system, but I am giving an example; If I wanted to write a WordPress style SEO package, I couldn't figure out how to run the modules inside other modules.
If I explain more, there is a sample posts and pages module and we also have an SEO module. I should be running this SEO module in the pages and posts module like WordPress.
can you help me for this? I need an idea.

If I explain more, there is a sample posts and pages module and we also have an SEO module. I should be running this SEO module in the pages and posts module like WordPress.
can you help me for this? I need an idea.

Comment: *****A WordPress style plugin management system.

Comment: FYI you can [edit] your question if you need to correct it. But before you do that, since you're new, and since this question is far too vague and unfocused for anyone to assist you with, I strongly advise you to take the [tour] and read [ask] (both of which the system recommended you to study _before_ you posted anything, but I can see from your badgeless profile that for some strange reason you ignored).

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) is also likely to be relevant. You need to explain much more specifically where you're getting stuck, show some evidence you've tried to research and solve it yourself, and ideally post a code attempt which is failing to work as you intended. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, it makes use of hooks (https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/)

So, your best bet will be to use this package https://github.com/SneherAdor/laravel-hooks I have not used this before, so you have to read up more.